# ColdFusion10 - query cfloop over an insert query

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet, cfloop

First post here.  I'm using `<CFSPREADSHEET>` to create a query from Excel and then trying to insert the query results into MySQL table.  That's working fine.  I also need to take a value from one column and insert its proper ID number into the ID column in the table.  Here's my code.  The results I'm getting is the same ID (6) is being inserted in each table row.  Help here would sure be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" 
 src="#myFile#" 
 sheet="5" 
 excludeheaderrow="true" 
 headerrow="1" 
 query="newQuery" />

<cfloop query="newQuery">
  <!--- set ID variables --->
  <cfif newQuery.Branch EQ "Army"> 
    <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 6 />
  <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Marine Corps">
    <cfset variables.Branch_ID EQ 9 />
  <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Navy">
    <cfset variables.Branch_ID EQ 7 />
  <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Air Force">
    <cfset variables.Branch_ID EQ 8 />
  <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Coast Guard">
    <cfset variables.Branch_ID EQ 10 />
  </cfif>

  <cfquery name="importXLS" datasource="memorials_mysql"> 
  INSERT INTO honorees_temp(FirsttName,MName,LastName,Branch,Branch_ID,Unit) 
  VALUES 
  ('#Trim(FirstName)#', 
   '#Trim(MName)#', 
   '#Trim(LastName)#',
   '#Trim(Branch)#', 
   #variables.Branch_ID#,  
   '#Trim(Unit)#') 
  </cfquery> 
</cfloop>
```

Comment: What ID field? Is ID a field in MySQL that should be auto_increment but is not?

Comment: If `Branch_ID` exists in a db table, you could also use  an `INSERT / SELECT` to select the ID from the other table and insert the values in the same statement, and eliminate the if/else blocks.

Answer (score 4):

One issue is you have a syntax error in your `cfset` statements. In cfset you need to use `=` instead of `EQ`.

```
<!--- set ID variables --->
    <cfif newQuery.Branch EQ "Army"> 
        <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 6 />
    <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Marine Corps">
        <cfset variables.Branch_ID =9 />
    <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Navy">
        <cfset variables.Branch_ID =7 />
    <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Air Force">
        <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 8 />
    <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Coast Guard">
        <cfset variables.Branch_ID =10 />
    </cfif>
```

What are your values of newQuery.Branch? If nothing is matched in your if statement it's going to retain the last value because it's not being re-initialized

You should also be using `<cfqueryparam>` on your INSERT statements.

Also, and this is more a personal preference, but using a cfswitch is more efficient than using multiple `else if` statements.

```
<cfswitch expression="#trim(newQuery.Branch)#">
  <cfcase value="Army" >
    <cfset Branch_ID = 6 />     
  </cfcase>
  <cfcase value="Marine Corps" >
    <cfset Branch_ID = 9 />     
  </cfcase>
  <cfcase value="Navy" >
    <cfset Branch_ID = 7 />     
  </cfcase>
  <cfcase value="Air Force" >
    <cfset Branch_ID = 8 />     
  </cfcase>
  <cfcase value="Coast Guard" >
    <cfset Branch_ID = 10 />    
  </cfcase>
  <cfdefaultcase>
    <!--- set either a default value or throw an error, depending on your needs --->
    <cfset Branch_ID = 0>
    <cfthrow message="Invalid Branch_ID">
  </cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Comment: Could also mention that this if statement is the perfect setup for a switch statement. Also, he `Trims()` `newQuery.Branch` in the insert but not the `cfif` [e] Add a default case to that switch too.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  Obviously that fixed the problem.  I do appreciate the quick help.  Hope I can provide some answers in the future.

Comment: "cfswitch, with a string expression, and especially under load, runs dramatically slower than the equivalent cfif-cfelseif-cfelse block." http://www.webapper.com/blog/index.php/2006/07/27/20060727042244/ This problem exists in CF8 and 9. I wouldn't be surprised if it still exists in CF10.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo and from the comments `Good news. I got around to trying this in CF8 today and the problem seems to be resolved.` Quick testing on CF9 showed that `cfswitch` was much faster, using his own test files.

Comment: ...unless there's no match for the `cfswitch` then `cfif` is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

reset your variables.brand_id to 0 each time you loop.  You are probably not getting a match in your IF statements so its retaining the value of the last match for each future unmatched record.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" 
               src="#myFile#" 
         sheet="5" 
         excludeheaderrow="true" 
         headerrow="1" 
         query="newQuery" />
<cfloop query="newQuery">
    **<cfset variables.Branch_id=0>**
        <!--- set ID variables --->
        <cfif newQuery.Branch EQ "Army"> 
            <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 6 />
        <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Marine Corps">
            <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 9 />
        <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Navy">
            <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 7 />
        <cfelseif newQuery.Branch = "Air Force">
            <cfset variables.Branch_= EQ 8 />
        <cfelseif newQuery.Branch EQ "Coast Guard">
            <cfset variables.Branch_ID = 10 />
        </cfif>

    <cfquery name="importXLS" datasource="memorials_mysql"> 
            INSERT INTO honorees_temp(FirsttName,MName,LastName,Branch,Branch_ID,Unit) 
            VALUES 
              ('#Trim(FirstName)#', 
               '#Trim(MName)#', 
               '#Trim(LastName)#',
               '#Trim(Branch)#', 
                #variables.Branch_ID#,  
               '#Trim(Unit)#') 
</cfquery> 
</cfloop>
```